# stringByAppendingString causing system to run out of memory for applications

Tags: objective-c

Can someone point me in the direction why my system tells me I'm running out of memory for applications when I run the following code over a "large" (37000 rows) text file?

```
-(void) writeToFile: (NSString*)filePath withSeparator:(NSString*) fieldSep{
NSString* completeFile = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@""] autorelease];
for(int i=0;i<[self numberOfRows];i++){
    printf("im at line number... %i of %i\n",i,[self numberOfRows]);
    for(int j=0;j<[self numberOfColumns];j++){
        completeFile = [completeFile stringByAppendingString:[self objectInRow:i column:j]];

        if(j<[self numberOfColumns]-1){
            //separator for all columns except last one
            completeFile = [completeFile stringByAppendingString:fieldSep];
        }
    }
        completeFile = [completeFile stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];
}
NSError *error = nil;
[completeFile writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO
                 encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:&error];
if(error){
    NSLog(@"Error writing file at %@\n%@",
          filePath, [error localizedFailureReason]);
}
```

}

I've added the printf for debugging reasons, first 4000 rows seem to happen instantly, then it slowly slows down... my file contains over 37000 rows similar to these:

```
1893-11-6   136 194 165
```

Comment: This is an example of [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter's_algorithm) in action.

Comment: Well, not Spolsky's example of it; `NSString` doesn't work like `strcat`. :)

Comment: @StevenFisher: Here a copy is made each time a string is appended, rather than the linear search for the 0 in Spolsky's `strcat` example. But the principle is the same - appending is O(n), so building the string is O(n^2).

Comment: I should have been more clear. The problem isn't exactly the same, but it's certainly the same principle at work. :)

Comment: thanks @RussellZahniser, I have read the wikipedia article and now I feel ashamed. Oh well, better to learn now than after a lot of written code! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you allocate objects using factory methods, the objects are added to the autoreleasepool. The autoreleasepool is only drained when your event loop runs, after your `IBAction` has returned.

The trick here would be to put the contents of your loop in its own autorelasepool.

But let's address the biggest problem first. There's a **NSMutableString** class that you should use here, which would drastically reduce the number of objects you need to create.

We'll switch completeFile to a **NSMutableString**, constructed using a factory method, then append to it:

```
-(void) writeToFile: (NSString*)filePath withSeparator:(NSString*) fieldSep{
    NSMutableString* completeFile = [NSMutableString string];
    for(int i=0;i<[self numberOfRows];i++){
        printf("im at line number... %i of %i\n",i,[self numberOfRows]);
        for(int j=0;j<[self numberOfColumns];j++){
            [completeFile appendString:[self objectInRow:i column:j]];

            if(j<[self numberOfColumns]-1){
                //separator for all columns except last one
                completeFile appendString:fieldSep];
            }
        }
            [completeFile appendString:@"\n"];
    }
    NSError *error = nil;
    [completeFile writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO
                     encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:&error];
    if(error){
        NSLog(@"Error writing file at %@\n%@",
              filePath, [error localizedFailureReason]);
    }
}
```

This leaves another problem, though. See that `[self objectInRow:i column:j]`? It's still (presumably) an autoreleased object. That won't get cleaned up.

We may have made your code run without crashing, depending on the size of the data, but it's a question of *when* it crashes not *if*.

To fix this, we need to introduce autoreleasepools. Let's do one per row **and** per column. This might seem excessive (and, indeed, it is in this case since we've eliminated autoreleasepool use in the outer loop) but autoreleasepools are pretty cheap. If you're doing a loop over a large amount of data, it's just good practice.

You can replace each of your for blocks with `@autorelease` blocks, for instance:

```
for(int i=0;i<[self numberOfRows];i++){
```

With:

```
for(int i=0;i<[self numberOfRows];i++) @autoreleasepool {
```

That gives us this code:

```
-(void) writeToFile: (NSString*)filePath withSeparator:(NSString*) fieldSep{
    NSMutableString* completeFile = [NSMutableString string];
    for(int i=0;i<[self numberOfRows];i++) @autoreleasepool {
        printf("im at line number... %i of %i\n",i,[self numberOfRows]);
        for(int j=0;j<[self numberOfColumns];j++) @autoreleasepool {
            [completeFile appendString:[self objectInRow:i column:j]];

            if(j<[self numberOfColumns]-1){
                //separator for all columns except last one
                completeFile appendString:fieldSep];
            }
        }
            [completeFile appendString:@"\n"];
    }
    NSError *error = nil;
    [completeFile writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO
                     encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:&error];
    if(error){
        NSLog(@"Error writing file at %@\n%@",
              filePath, [error localizedFailureReason]);
    }
}
```

A final note, though. Your error check here is not safe. What happens to an error pointer passed in like this on **success** isn't defined.

```
    [completeFile writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO
                     encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:&error];
    if(error){
        NSLog(@"Error writing file at %@\n%@",
              filePath, [error localizedFailureReason]);
    }
```

Instead, you want this:

```
    BOOL ok = [completeFile writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO
                     encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:&error];
    if(!ok){
        NSLog(@"Error writing file at %@\n%@",
              filePath, [error localizedFailureReason]);
    }
```

This, then, should do what you want.

Comment: ARC is not used here. See the call to `autorelease`?

Comment: Oops, sorry. Didn't notice. Well, ARC should be used.

Comment: Absolutely. And I think **NSMutableString** should be used, too. :)

Comment: @LeoNatan even if ARC was in use, it does not replace autoreleased objects with retained ones. Autorelease pools can still be used in tight loops to minimise memory footprint

Comment: @LeoNatan You have misunderstood that article. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825976/under-arc-is-it-still-advisable-to-create-an-autoreleasepool-for-loops for more information.

Comment: Generally, I think it's a mistake to assume you'll get the `objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue` optimization (and everything it implies). There's a lot of things that can throw it off. It's better to just think out what you want to do and then express it clearly in code.

Comment: Better to not abuse the autorelease system altogether. :) Mutable string is there for a reason.

Comment: Absolutely, switch to mutable string. But you're not going to be able to completely avoid an autoreleasepool here. It's a question of *when* it will fail, not *if*: `[self objectInRow:i column:j]` is going to continue to return an autorelased object, for instance. You'll need a pool just for that, eventually.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, I appreciate it. Thanks too for adding a correction for the error check!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that each call of `stringByAppendingString:` creates a new autoreleased `NSString` objects. However, since the method continues in a loop, autorelease does not get a chance to free these objects.

You can solve it by adding an autorelease pool around the inner loop, like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<[self numberOfRows];i++){
    printf("im at line number... %i of %i\n",i,[self numberOfRows]);
    @autoreleasepool {
        for(int j=0;j<[self numberOfColumns];j++){
            completeFile = [completeFile stringByAppendingString:[self objectInRow:i column:j]];

            if(j<[self numberOfColumns]-1){
                //separator for all columns except last one
                completeFile = [completeFile stringByAppendingString:fieldSep];
            }
        }
    }
        completeFile = [completeFile stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `NSMutableString` to append these strings.

Comment: This indeed fixed it, I changed to NSMutableString and used completeFile appendString in stead of stringByAppendingString and it does all 37000 rows almost instantly. Thank you everyone for replying !

Comment: Yeah. NSMutableString is pretty efficient. I don't know exactly what it's algorithm is for resizing, but it's certainly smarter than reallocating on every append. :)